# how to count the value of multiple elements in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this xslt code to count the abstract length of type main:

```
<xsl:variable name="mainAbstract">
    <xsl:value-of select="string-length(normalize-space(abstract[@type = 'main']))"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

and I had an issue where I had multiple xml tags that matches the same pattern and it's not working.

How should I count the number of characters in multiple elements from this select statement?

Comment: Please include sample Xml data to provide a [mcve] illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple `abstract` elements of type main, then you need  to select which one you want to process.

If - as it seems - you want the **sum** of their individual string-lenghts, then do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(abstract[@type = 'main']/string-length(normalize-space()))"/>
```